# java connection pool, how many max connections in a multithreaded batch?

Tags: java, spring, atomikos

I have a Java batch which does a select with a large resulset (I process the elements using a Spring callbackhandler). 
The callbackhandler puts a task in a fixed threadpool to process the row. 
My poolsize is fixed on 16 threads. 
The resulset contains about 100k elements.
All db access code is handled through a JdbcTemplate or through Hibernate/Spring, no manual connection management is present.
I have tried with Atomikos and with Commons DBCP as connection pool.

Now, I would think that 17 max connections in my connectionpool would be enough to get this batch to finish. One for the select and 16 for the threads in the connectionpool which update some rows. However that seems to be too naive, as I have to specify a max pool size a magnitude larger (haven't tried for an exact value), first I tried 50 which worked on my local Windows machine, but doesn't seem to be enough on our Unix test environment. There I have to specify 128 to make it work (again, I didn't even try a value between 50 and 128, I went straight to 128).

Is this normal? Is there some fundamental mechanism in connection pooling I'm missing? I find it hard to debug this as I don't know how to see what happens with the opened connections. I tried various log4j settings but didn't get any satisfactory result.

edit, additional info: when the connectionpool size seems to be too low, the batch seems to hang. If I do a jstat on the process I can see all threads are waiting for a new connection. At first I didn't specify the maxWait property on the dbcp connection pool, which causes threads to wait indefinitely on a new connection, and I noticed the batch kept hanging. So no connections were released. However, that only happened after processing +-70k rows, which dismissed my initial hunch of connection leakage somehow.

edit2: I forgot to mention I already rewrote the update part in my tasks. I qeueu my updates in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, I empty that on 1000 elements. So i actually only do about 100 updates.

edit3: I'm using Oracle and I am using the concurrent utils. So i have an executor configured with fixed poolsize of 16. I submit my tasks on this executor. I don't use connections manually in my tasks, I use jdbctemplate which is threadsafe and asks it connections from the connectionpool. I suppose Spring/DBCP handles the connection/thread issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to c3p0 instead of DBCP. In c3p0 you can specify a number of helper threads. I notice if I put that number as high as the number of threads I'm using, the number of connections stays really low (using the handy jmx bean of c3p0 to inspect the active connections). Also,  I have several dependencies with each its own entity manager. Apparently a new connection is needed for each entity manager, so I have about 4 entitymanagers/thread, which would explain the high number of connections. I think my tasks are all so short-lived that DBCP couldn't follow with closing/releasing connections, since c3p0 works more asynchronous and you can specify the number of helperthreads, it is able to release my connections in time.

edit: but the batch keeps hanging when deployed to the test environment, all threads are blocking when releasing the connection, the lock is on the pool. Just the same as with DBPC :(

edit: all my problems dissapeared when I switched to BoneCP, and I got a huge performance increase as bonus too

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux, you can try MySql administrator to monitor you connection status graphically, provided you are using MySQL.

Irrespective of that, even 100 connections is not uncommon for large enterprise applications, handling a few thousand requests per minute.

But if the requests are low or each request doesnt need unique a transaction, then I would recommend you to tune your operation inside threads.

That is, how are you distributing the 100k elements to 16 threads?
If you try to acquire the connection every time you read a row from the shared location(or buffer), then it is expected to take time.

See whether this helps.

1. getConnection
2. for each element until the buffer size becomes zero
3. process it.
4. if you need to update,
5. open a transaction
6. update
7. commit/rollback the transaction
8. go to step 2
9. release the connection

you can synchronize the buffer by using [java.util.concurrent collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Dont use one Runnable/Callable for each element. This will degrade the performance.
Also how are you creating threads? use Executors to run your runnable/callable. Also remember that DB connections are NOT expected to be shared across threads. So use 1 connection in 1 thread at a time.

For eg. create an Executor and submit 16 runnalbles each having its own connection.

Comment: I edited my question with more information. Performance is actually very good even though I create a Runnable / row.

Comment: Try Netbeans profiler. It gives you live stats about the threads such as waiting for CPU, waiting for Lock, Waiting for IO, etc. If the result shows that threads are waiting for DB connection, then it is good to increase the pool size. Otherwise optimize the bottle neck.  http://profiler.netbeans.org/

Comment: I used jvisualvm for that. Unfortunately I can't connect a profiler to the unix env where the problem is occuring, it's a locked down environment. But I'm not really interested in tuning my pool size, it works ok now with 128 and my source data size is constant so that should be good. My question however is, shouldn't 17 be enough? And if not, why?

Comment: I dont have direct answer for your last question because that is based on the need of your application. Until you profile in some way (using profiler/using visualvm/add logs), noone can tell where your application spends most of the time. However as I said earlier, having upto 100 is not uncommon as long as your DB server has enough resource. One optimization here is, if you go with high number of connections, you can drop them and get a new one, if idle time is high.

Comment: I know it is not uncommon, I have webapplications running in production with pools of 500, since there you can't really predict the number of threads. But in this case, there are only 17 threads which connect to the database, so I don't quite understand why you would think the poolsize depends on the need of the application? I have profiled, and it shows 98% utilization of the threads, so virtually no waiting on connections. You mention idle time, I'm not sure yet where that comes into play? Btw, I do appreciate your answers :)

Comment: So right now you have 17 connection and 17 threads. Try increasing the no. of threads. This will give you answer whether you can/have to increase the pool size. Hope this helps.

Comment: The idle time i mentioned is the time the connections are idle between the operations, ie. time between two batch of 100k